# how to use rem font size in react native for both android and ios

Tags: android, react-native, react-hooks, fonts

Is there any way to use rem font size in react native for both android and ios?
I also use npm i react-native-extended-stylesheet but it doesn't work on react native for mobile. It works on web but not on mobile.
Is there any solution?
And my client wants only rem fonts not px, or any other font size.

Answer (score 0):

We can do it with using styled component and also use this library ---

*[styled-components/native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/styled-components)*

```
const Container = styled.View`
flex: 1;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
`;

const Text = styled.Text`
font-size: 18rem;
color: blue;
font-weight: 500;
`;

export default function TextApp() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: its not working, if working please share proper code of lines.